# How can use data file with Eclipse-clp program

Tags: prolog, eclipse-clp

How can use data file with Eclipse-clp or Prolog program. for Variables and Array values. for example if you want to give data to program as an big Array.How can read this data from a data files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ECLiPSe includes a CSV library:

http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/csv/index.html

This library allows you to parse a CSV file into lists, which you can then convert into an array using another library:

http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib_public/arrays/index.html

Comment: very thanks , Then ECLipse does not read data file like MiniZinc?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having your data in Prolog syntax, it is trivial.  Just open a file and use read/2 to read it:

```
open(File, read, Stream), read(Stream, Data), close(Stream), ...
```

The file should then contain a single Prolog term, which can be of any valid Prolog type such as structure, list, array, number, string, and arbitrarily nested.